# List can only store one item in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Im struggling to pass data from view into a list in the controller.

I can add 1 item to the list, but when the controller goes back to the view to recieve another input from the user, the previous item in the list is replaced with the new one. The last item just isnt there anymore, so the list always has just 1 item in the count. Its almost like it just resets everytime the user input a new string. As if it cant store more than one string at a time.

I want to store multiple user inputs in the AddTagVM.StringList, so that I can eventually retrieve and print them in a view.

This is my model:

```
public class AddTagVM
{
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public List<Tag> TagList { get; set; }

    public List<string> StringList { get; set; } = new List<string>();

    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddTag()
{
    AddTagVM tagg = new AddTagVM();
    
    return View(tagg);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTag(AddTagVM tagg)
{
    //tagg.Tag[tagg.Add].Name = tagg.TagName;

    tagg.StringList.Add(tagg.TagName);
    
    return View(tagg);
}
```

And this is the view:

```
@model BlogNiKRaMu.Models.AddTagVM
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddTag";
}

<h2>AddTag</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
                       
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.TagName)
        
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove  `= new List<string>();` from the VM first as see if it works as expected.

Else try to do it like this.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddTag(AddTagVM tagg)
{
    var tag = tagg.TagName; // <---Extract the value to a variable first.
    tagg.StringList.Add(tag);
    
    return View(tagg);
}
```

Comment: hi! I tried removing the  ``= new List<string>();``, but then it just gives me a System.NullReferenceException.                                                                                                                      Edit: I tried to extract value to variable aswell, still didnt work:/ I really dont understand why it has to be so hard? I mean, in a console application, this would work totally fine!:/

Comment: From what line? Have you tried to add a breake point to HttpPost method and see what happens?

Comment: Yes, it just says object reference not set to an instance of an object

Answer (score 0):

When you post back the form, your AddTagVM object will only have TagName input not the list value as you lose the list. Meaning, when post the form, the request should contain all the values you need to retain in the object i.e the StringList should also be posted along with string.

So the work around you can try is, you can add HidderFor to the StringList. This way when the form post the object will have value for TagName and StringList as well.

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StringList) 
 @for(int i= 0; i<StringList.count(); i++) 
 {  
     @Html.HiddenFor(model=>model.StringList[i]) 
 }
```

Comment: Hello! Thank you for answering! Should I add these two lines underneath the TagName in the view? Thanks!

Comment: Inside form elements you can add anywhere you want.

Comment: Thank you!:) Appreciate it alot!

Comment: Hi again! I think the best way to deal with this is with Ajax! I asked my teacher and he said so too. Anyway, I appreciate your comment and that you checked with me again:) Hope you have a great day!